# path directory not being recognised by my code

Tags: python, module, directory, filepath

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37Sya.png)My code will not recognise my path directory or allow me to import other modules within the same root directory. Here below is my code:

```
import streamlit as st
from sentimentanalysis import save_audio
```

and here is the error I am being returned with:
No module named 'sentimentanalysis'

I have tried:

- numerous things such as adding **init**.py.
- Checked the codes directory using `import sys;print(sys.path[0])` which returns the directory I expect.

The directory path is:

sentimentanalysis(root directory)

- Save_audio

  - save_audio
- app.py

  - app.y
- Configure.py

  - configure.py

Comment: [Please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), include it as text, within code fences etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to import like this :

```
from sentimentanalysis.Save_audio import save_audio
```

Module structure mean directory groupping. 
So you have no global view about what inside package. 
Also it is important to have `__init__.py` inside module dir.
 Otherwise relative import only option